# What is the meaning of "RELEASE" in Clojure boot-clj?

Tags: clojure, boot-clj

I have created a new Clojure boot-clj project using `boot-new`. In the 'build.boot' file I see the below line.

```
[org.clojure/clojure "RELEASE"]
```

What does the "RELEASE" mean in the above context? And what version that dependency points to? I don't see any files that pass some environment variable or something. If it means "the latest version", won't it cause issues if some backward compatibility breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Maven feature (like all JVM dependency management tools Boot integrates with the Maven infrastructure). `RELEASE` refers to the latest release (not snapshot) version.

Maven repositories record the latest released version. See for example the metadata for org.clojure/clojure at Maven central, https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/clojure/clojure/maven-metadata.xml, at path `metadata/versioning/release`.

An argument can be made for and against using this. For me, pinning of the version and reproducibility are important, so I avoid this notation.